# Soft Link created for new software installation

Tags: software-installation, symlink

When we install a new software, after extraction the below steps are performed generally:

1. move the files to `/opt/folder`
2. create the symlink

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/folder/application_folder_name  /usr/bin/application_folder_name
   ```

Why do we need a softlink here?

Also why the `install.sh` script present in application folder doesn't start the installation process?

Comment: It is far more common to link `application_name`: `sudo ln -s /opt/application_folder_name/application_name /usr/bin/application_name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That way you can start the program without extending the search path (`$PATH`) in which the shell searches for binaries/executables, and also without copying the them in the `/usr/bin` directory (or other directory in `$PATH`).

This has minor space advantages (if `/opt` and `/usr` are on different partitions), but more importantly the so linked executable, can follow the link from the invocation path (`/usr/bin/application_name` to `/opt/folder/application_name`) and so find out where it was in stalled. That makes it possible to have some `/opt/folder/data` directory without having to configure `application_name` and it still can find that directory based on where the real executable (found via the link) is.¹

As for the second part of your question: there is no automatic start of `install.sh` from using `tar`, that is just a name recognised by humans as something they need to start in order to install (just like `tar`, or any other extraction program will not show you the README either).

¹ <sub>An executable is handed its invocation path as first argument (in python to `sys.argv[0]`, in C to the first element of the `char *` array handed as the second parameter to `main()`</sub>